# For positive $a$, $b$, $c$ with $abc=1$, show that $\sum_{cyc}\sqrt{a^2-a+1}\geq a+b+c$

Tags: inequality, contest-math, substitution, cauchy-schwarz-inequality, mixing-variables

> Let $a,b,c$ are positive number such that $abc=1$. Prove that:
>   $$\sqrt{a^2-a+1}+\sqrt{b^2-b+1}+\sqrt{c^2-c+1}\;\geq\; a+b+c$$

This problem froms my Math teacher. I have attempted to let $$(a,b,c)=(\frac{x}{y}, \frac{y}{z}, \frac{z}{x})$$. The inequality is equivalent to: $\frac{\sqrt{x^2-xy+y^2}}{y}+\frac{\sqrt{y^2-yz+z^2}}{z}+\frac{\sqrt{x^2-xz+z^2}}{x}\geq \frac{x}{y}+\frac{y}{z}+\frac{z}{x}$

Then, I tried to use AM-GM but I stucked on it.

Comment: I solved your problem. If you want to see my solution, show please your attempts.

Comment: I have attempted to let $(a,b,c)=(\frac{x}{y}, \frac{y}{z}, \frac{z}{x})$ or $(\frac{x^2}{yz}, \frac{y^2}{xz}, \frac{z^2}{xy})$
But I don't know what I will do next.

Comment: Show it please.

Comment: Let $(a,b,c)=(\frac{x}{y}, \frac{y}{z}, \frac{z}{x})$. The inequality is equivalent to:
$\sum \frac{\sqrt{x^2-xy+y^2}}{y}\geq \sum \frac{x}{y}$
$\sqrt{x^2-xy+y^2}=\sqrt{\frac{3}{4}(x+y)^2+\frac{1}{4}(x+y)^2}\geq \frac{1}{2}(x+y)$
$\Rightarrow \sum \frac{\sqrt{x^2-xy+y^2}}{y}\geq \sum \frac{x+y}{2y}$.

But $\sum \frac{x+y}{2y}\leq \sum \frac{x}{y}$-> wrong.

Then, I tried to use inequality $\sqrt{x^2-xy+y^2}\geq \frac{x^2+y^2}{x+y}$ but I don't know how to prove $\sum \frac{x^2+y^2}{x+y}\geq \sum \frac{x}{y}$
...........

Comment: You can keep squaring until there are integer index both sides and using the Müirhead’s Inequality

Comment: @Analyn_a: Please [edit] the question and add all relevant information there: Where does the problem come from? What have to tried to solve the problem? Where are you stuck? That information should be in the question itself, not in the comments.

Answer (score 2):

The hint:

Use the Mixing Variables method.

Indeed, we can use the beautiful Can's idea.

Since $$\prod\limits_{cyc}(a-1)^2=\prod_{cyc}((a-1)(b-1))\geq0,$$ we can assume that $$(a-1)(b-1)\geq0$$ or
$$a+b\leq1+ab=1+\frac{1}{c}.$$

Thus, by C-S:

\begin{align}
\sqrt{a^2-a+1}&+\sqrt{b^2-b+1}\\
&=\sqrt{a^2+b^2-a-b+2+2\sqrt{(a^2-a+1)(b^2-b+1)}}\\
&\geq\sqrt{a^2+b^2-a-b+2+2\sqrt{\left(\left(a-\frac{1}{2}\right)^2+\frac{3}{4}\right)\left(\left(b-\frac{1}{2}\right)^2+\frac{3}{4}\right)}}\\
&\geq\sqrt{a^2+b^2-a-b+2+2\left(\left(a-\frac{1}{2}\right)\left(b-\frac{1}{2}\right)+\frac{3}{4}\right)}\\
&=\sqrt{a^2+b^2-a-b+2+2ab-a-b+2}\\
&=\sqrt{(a+b)^2-2(a+b)+4}.
\end{align}

But $f(x)=\sqrt{x^2-2x+4}-x$ decreases, which says
$$\sum_{cyc}(\sqrt{a^2-a+1}-a)\geq f(a+b)+\sqrt{c^2-c+1}-c\geq$$
$$\geq f\left(1+\frac{1}{c}\right)+\sqrt{c^2-c+1}-c=\sqrt{3+\frac{1}{c^2}}-1-\frac{1}{c}+\sqrt{c^2-c+1}-c.$$
Id est, it's enough to prove that:
$$\sqrt{3+\frac{1}{c^2}}-1-\frac{1}{c}+\sqrt{c^2-c+1}-c\geq0$$ and the rest is smooth.

Can you end it now?

Comment: Great! Thank you so much dear Michael Rozenberg!

Comment: @Analyn_a You are welcome!